# React testing library - nested components keep parent from rendering properly

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am brand new to react testing library. I am testing a component that renders an error message. I want to test that the error message renders properly. This component has a nest component that I do not want to test. It appears that the nested component is preventing the parent component from rendering properly in my test.

Component:

```
import React from "react";

import Confirm from "components/Confirm";

interface Props {
  error?: string;
}

function ErrorPage({ error }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const renderErrors = () => {
    return <>{error && <p>{error}</p>}</>;
  };

  return (
    <Confirm
      title="Error"
      action=""
    >
      <p>An error occurred while processing the request.</p>
      {renderErrors()}
    </Confirm>
  );
}

export default ErrorPage;
```

Test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import ErrorPage from "./ErrorPage";

describe("ErrorPage", () => {
  const message = "There was an error";
  it("renders successfully", () => {
    render(<ErrorPage error={message} />);
  });

  it("displays the error",() => {
    const { getByText } = render(<ErrorPage error={message} />);
    screen.debug();
    expect(getByText("There was an error")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

My first test passes, my second test fails.

Output from `screen.debug()`

```
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

Error from second test:

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: There was an error. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div />
    </body>

      12 |     const { getByText } = render(<ErrorPage error={message} />);
      13 |     screen.debug();
    > 14 |     expect(getByText("There was an error")).toBeInTheDocument();
         |            ^
      15 |   });
      16 | });
      17 |
```

When I remove the nested component, `<Confirm />` and replace is with a simple `<div></div>` the tests pass.

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  error?: string;
}

function ErrorPage({ error }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const renderErrors = () => {
    return <>{error && <p>{error}</p>}</>;
  };

  return (
    <div
    >
      <p>An error occurred while processing the request.</p>
      {renderErrors()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ErrorPage;
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to somehow stub the `<Confirm/>` component?

Comment: I assume `<Confirm>` doesn't render its children right away, and there's some logic involved? One option would be to stub that component, to avoid having to deal with the extra logic and go for the unit test approach. Another option would be to include the steps needed to render the children, working more as an integration test.

Comment: Thanks for your input @juliomalves - I would prefer to stub the component. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

If you set it to a variable like `const  theErrorPage = <ErrorPage error={message} />` then you can do `theErrorPage.getByText`